# Automatically increasing the value of a variable in generate_series

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2, generate-series

I ran into the need to automatically increment the value of a variable in generate_series. By the condition of the business logic, the field identifier in the model does not increase automatically.

I decided to try to find the maximum id value in advance and, within the of the generation, try to simply increase it by 1. But I don't understand how to do this correct.

```
max_id = Companies.objects.aggregate(Max('id'))  # {'id__max': 1529367}
value = max_id['id__max']

cursor.execute(f'''
    INSERT INTO test.companies(
                    id, name, city_id, revenue, labors
                )
    SELECT  {value} = {value}+1,   # This is what I want, but I don't know how to do it 
           (
                SELECT x[1 + ((random() * 25)::INT) % 3]
                FROM (
                    SELECT '{{Google,Yandex,Amazon}}'::text[]
                ) AS z2(x)
                WHERE SEQ = SEQ
            ),
           (random() * 3000)::INT,
           (random() * 3000)::INT,
           (random() * 3000)::INT

    FROM generate_series(1,10)  SEQ;
''')
```

All this I do as part of my work for Python Django.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any obstacle to run your iteration from 1 to 10 in Python instead of SQL?
Besides that, I think you missed VALUES in your SQL statement.

```
max_id = Companies.objects.aggregate(Max('id'))  # {'id__max': 1529367}
value = max_id['id__max']
```

```
for addval in range(1,10):
    cursor.execute(f'''
        INSERT INTO test.companies(id, name, city_id, revenue, labors)
        VALUES (''' + value+addval + ''',
           (
                SELECT x[1 + ((random() * 25)::INT) % 3]
                FROM (
                    SELECT '{{Google,Yandex,Amazon}}'::text[]
                ) AS z2(x)
                WHERE SEQ = ''' + addval + '''
            ),
           (random() * 3000)::INT,
           (random() * 3000)::INT,
           (random() * 3000)::INT
        )
     '''
```

**EDIT**
If you want to do it all with PostgreSQL, why don't you start your generate_series from value+1?:

```py
max_id = Companies.objects.aggregate(Max('id'))  # {'id__max': 1529367}
value = max_id['id__max']

cursor.execute(f'''
    INSERT INTO test.companies(
                    id, name, city_id, revenue, labors
                )
    SELECT  SEQ,
                SELECT x[1 + ((random() * 25)::INT) % 3]
                FROM (
                    SELECT '{{Google,Yandex,Amazon}}'::text[]
                ) AS z2(x)
                WHERE SEQ = SEQ
            ,
           (random() * 3000)::INT,
           (random() * 3000)::INT,
           (random() * 3000)::INT

    FROM generate_series(''' value + 1 ''',10)  SEQ;
''')
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but on the contrary, I want to get by with clean sql. If use Python iteration, then creating random records will only be done for one object at a time.  psql generate_series does it in a different way, allowing you to create many records at once, which should give a noticeable increase in speed, but working with it gives me difficulties)